# How to export highcharts with specified fill color for highcharts background?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have highcharts defined in angular and with the help of a toggle-button, 
I can alter the .highcharts-background color (which is done using css files). 
This is working fine on the browser, but when exported I am getting default white color.
Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use styled mode, styles from CSS classes will not be applied on an exported chart. Use `backgroundColor` property instead:

```
chart: {
  backgroundColor: 'red'
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tsjmkrbw/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.styledMode

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.backgroundColor